# error: class "cooperative_groups::__v1::thread_block" has no member "is_valid"

Tags: cuda, gpu-cooperative-groups

We are trying to use some of the cooperative groups features in CUDA to write a small application. We are using Tesla V100 card with CUDA 11.0.
But on using is_valid() method in thread_block the below error is observed:

```
error: class "cooperative_groups::__v1::thread_block" has no member "is_valid"
```

In the CUDA provided sample simpleCooperativeGroups.cu,  in the kernel cgkernel() when the is_valid method is used, this error can be seen. The code snippet from the modified sample looks as below.

```
__global__ void cgkernel(){


// threadBlockGroup includes all threads in the block
thread_block threadBlockGroup = this_thread_block();
int threadBlockGroupSize=threadBlockGroup.size();

// workspace array in shared memory required for reduction
extern __shared__ int workspace[];

int input, output, expectedOutput;

// input to reduction, for each thread, is its' rank in the group
input=threadBlockGroup.thread_rank();

// expected output from analytical formula (n-1)(n)/2
// (noting that indexing starts at 0 rather than 1)
expectedOutput=(threadBlockGroupSize-1)*threadBlockGroupSize/2;

// perform reduction
output=sumReduction(threadBlockGroup, workspace, input);

bool valid = threadBlockGroup.is_valid();
.
.
.
}
```

Any suggestions to resolve this would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

studying `cooperative_groups.h`, it appears that the only cg classes for which `is_valid()` method is provided are `grid_group` and `multi_grid_group`.

Therefore at this time, these are the only groups for which the method is available, you should not attempt to use that method with other group types; I think the best assumption is that other group types are always considered valid.

I suspect the logic here is that grid and multi-grid groups have proper launch configuration and platform requirements; they can be invalid.  The other group types cannot be invalid (at least in those respects) to create on any supported platform or launch configuration.  I don't intend that as a bulletproof statement under any possible interpretation, but a general guide or reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in this blog, developer.nvidia.com/blog/cooperative-groups it is mentioned that the class thread_group has the member is_valid() to check the validity of the group. Since the thread_block group extends the thread_group interface, this also should have is_valid(). But as it is observed in cooperative_groups.h, is_valid() method is provided only in grid_group and multi_grid_group.  Any idea if this was changed recently but the document still has it. Is the understanding right.

Comment: I looked in the `cooperative_groups.h` associated with both CUDA 9.2 and CUDA 11.x, and observed the same thing with respect to `is_valid()`, it was only provided for those groups I mentioned.  So I don't see that anything has changed in that timeframe.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that in the cuda programming guide, is_valid() is provided only for the groups that you have mentioned. We were confused with this  https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cooperative-groups/  probably.   Do you think the description needs to be changed in this blog.  This one seem to be appearing first when googled about cooperative groups.